# how to include ID tag defined in php file into html file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

now ID tag is defined in php file for div tag.  contents .
how can i invoke this ID tag in another html file or php file.

Comment: You can post some code please?

Answer (score 1):

You could also pass the variable to the new page via a QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for sending id tag value to a different html or php page OR you can use session on certain event assign value to a session variable and use as per your requirements